# How to find the matched SIFT features that are spatially consistent?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, features

I have extracted **DenseSIFT** from the query and database image and quantized by `kmeans`. The challenge is to find those SIFT features that quantized to the same visual words and be spatially consistent (have a similar position to object centers). I have tried few techniques:

1. using FLANN() on the SIFT (normal SIFT) coordinates on both query and database image and find the nearest neighbor and then comparing the visual words (NOTE: this gave few points that did not work).
2. Using [Coherent-Point-Drift (CPD)](https://github.com/siavashk/pycpd) on SIFT coordinates to find the matched points (I am not sure about this whether it is a right solution or not).

I am struggling with it for many days, and I hope experts can guide me with this. What are the possible solutions or algorithms that I can use for solving this?